# 2 Update methods in one route to swap date NodeJS, Mongoose+mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, mongoose

Im trying to create a route that takes in 2 dates and swap those dates with each other in the database.

the update method works outside of the forEach but not inside how can I get to work inside of the forEach ?

```
// @route   PATCH api/swap
// @desc    replace date
// @access  Public

router.put("/swap", (req, res) => {
  const firstDate = req.body.firstDate;
  const secondDate = req.body.secondDate;

  // console.log(firstDate, secondDate);

  // Card.updateOne({ date: firstDate }, { $set: { date: secondDate } });
  Card.find()
    .then(cards => {
      cards.forEach(card => {
        if (card.date === firstDate) {
          return card.updateOne(
            { date: firstDate },
            { $set: { date: secondDate } }
          );
        } else if (card.date === secondDate) {
          return card.updateOne(
            { date: secondDate },
            { $set: { date: firstDate } }
          );
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
    })
    .then(() => console.log("working"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to achieve, you need to use a [QueryCursor](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-cursor) which would allow you to modify the documents one by one.

You can do something like this,

```
Card.find()
  .cursor()
  .on('data', function(card) { 

      if (card.date === firstDate) {
          card.set("date", secondDate);
      } else if (card.date === secondDate) {
          card.set("date", firstDate);
      }

      card.save(function(err){
      });  
   })
  .on('end', function() { console.log('Done!'); });
```

Comment: I just tried this but returned   card.set(date: secondDate)
[0]                                                        ^^^^
[0]
[0] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: There was a typo. Sorry for that. See the updated answer.

Comment: the function is executing but the data isn't changing in the db but its returning the "done" console log

Comment: Print the `err` in console in the call back function of `save` method to see if there's an error while saving the data.

Comment: Ok i just added the console and consoled the err,  it returned me 18 nulls,  18 is the number of cards i have in the db

Comment: It means there was no error. Put console in `if` and `else if` to see whether it goes inside them or not.

Comment: In my model i remove     date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  } .     to  =>     date: {
    type: String,
    default: Date.now
  } . Its working

Comment: well actually thats going to mess up when i post a new date, is there a work around instead of replacing date with string?

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the anonymous function within the `forEach` supports promises, which can be achieved through the `async` keyword.

Try this:

```
      cards.forEach(async (card) => {
          return card.updateOne(
...
```

In addition, [`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) might be a better tool for the job so you can avoid iterating through the entire collection of `Card` objects on every request and offload that to the `query` parameter to the database call.

Comment: I added async in the foreach but I'm getting the same result